# Facebook Messenger WebView with allowpaymentrequest

Tags: facebook, iframe, facebook-messenger

I'm not using Facebook Messenger's payment API. I am integrating with Visa Checkout manually.

I am able to integrate with Visa Checkout with no issues on a top-level test page. What I mean by top-level is that I am loading it directly as a test outside an iframe.

When I load such a payment page in an iframe, which is something that I have to do when using Facebook Messenger web view, Visa Checkout fails because the iframe doesn't have the allowpaymentrequest attribute. I don't have access to the iframe since it is generated by Messenger automatically when the webview with my payment page is opened.

I don't think I can just access this parent iFrame and call some "setAttribute" method?

So what can I do?

**EDIT**: This is the error message that Visa Checkout sdk throws, this is a standard PaymentRequest API thing.

`Error creating payment request DOMException: Failed to construct 'PaymentRequest': Must be in a top-level browsing context or an iframe needs to specify 'allowpaymentrequest' explicitly`

Comment: There is no way for you to control the attributes on the iframe

Comment: Yeah, this is kind of what I was expecting. I'm finding if Visa Checkout can fallback to something other than the RequestPayment API.

Comment: On a separate but related note, Facebook have the option for a Payment webview, but they only support "Facebook" payments and that's only in a small set of countries, even limited to some states in the US as far as I was able to see.